# How to tell the version of CloudStation client and server, and tell if they are updated to the newest version

Tags: synology

When trying to set up CloudStation on my computer, I get the following error message.

```
Please make sure Cloud Station is updated to the latest version 
both on the DiskStation and your computer, and then try again.
```

I believe it is all of the newest version, so what do I do from here. Well one step could be to find the version numbers of client and server.

Next step is to find out what are the most recent version numbers.

But how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Finding client version number in Linux:**

```
$cat ~/.CloudStation/CloudStation-app/INFO 
VERSION="3111"
ICONOVERLAY_VERSION="3"
```

**Finding client version number in Windows:**

Look in file `C:\Users\User name\AppData\Local\CloudStation\app\INFO`

**Finding server version number:**

I have not been able to find a version number for CloudStation, but to find the version of DSM (Disk Station Manager) look in Control Panel -> Update and Restore

[image]

Since it does not offer any updates, I guess that means that DSM, and the CloudStation server app is the most recent version.

**Finding most recent version of client**

At this address https://www.synology.com/en-global/releaseNote/CloudStation is a list of updates, with the most recent in the top. I think these are for the clients, but perhaps they refer to updates on the server too.